# Gson Parsing error with salt-net-api

Tags: json, gson, salt

Trying to parse the output of Salt CherryPy REST interface. The Json is provided as below,

```
{"info": [{"Function": "cmd.run", "jid": "20161111182415841377", "Target": "yesMyMaster", "Target-type": "glob", "User": "saltdev", "StartTime": "2016, Nov 11 18:24:15.841377", "Arguments": ["echo HELLO"], "Minions": ["yesMyMaster"], "Result": {}}], "return": [{}]}
```

This results in the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 147 path $.info[0].StartTime

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
```

The code is very simple, nothing special.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ResultInfoSet resultInfos = gson.fromJson(json, ResultInfoSet.class);
```

ResultInfo is a class from [Salt-Net-Api](https://github.com/SUSE/salt-netapi-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/suse/salt/netapi/results/ResultInfo.java)

Have anyone faced similar error before with Gson?

**Update**

If I remove `"StartTime": "2016, Nov 11 18:24:15.841377"` from json, then Gson works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same type adapters the library is using.
You can find a full example [here](https://github.com/SUSE/salt-netapi-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/suse/salt/netapi/parser/JsonParser.java#L45).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the JsonParser class which is part of the library @lucidd `ResultInfoSet resultInfoSet = JsonParser.JOB_RESULTS.parse(json_str);` parses it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **date format** as mentioned below and define the field as Date in POJO class.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") 
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();
```

**Field definition in POJO:-**

```
@SerializedName("StartTime")
    private Date startTime;
```